# Selenium Firefox WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using following in my program on ubuntu:

```
this.mDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

then

```
driver.get("http://test.com");
```

I get an error message meaning to say that the Firefox version used is the latest and I need to use an older version.

I downloaded Firefox and extracted it. Added it to the path.

I modified the code as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("/opt/firefox16/firefox")), profile);
```

When I execute /opt/firefox16/firefox  from the terminal, it starts the browser.

But when I execute the WebDriver code lines above, It still does not invoke the Firefox browser. I don't get any error messages.

Please, can someone guide me on how to start Firefox when the WebDriver is created and executed?

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? What OS?

Comment: Can you debug the execution to see where it is waiting?

Comment: Are you really testing against `http://test.com`? Or was that just an example?  I've seen some misleading errors that went away when I put in the correct url... So if your real url is something other than what you posted above, that could be a clue.

Answer (score 7):

The problem you are having is a common one.  All too often a new version of Firefox will not work with the latest version of Selenium Firefox WebDriver.

The solution is to **use compatible versions** of Firefox and Selenium Firefox WebDriver.

I recommend the following:

- Version **2.33.0** for Selenium Firefox WebDriver
- Version **18.0.2** for Firefox

This combination has always worked well for me.

You can also see which version of Selenium Firefox WebDriver is (theoretically) compatible with which versions of Firefox in the **[Release Notes](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG).**

Comment: I'm using exact same versions as you suggested, but its seems to failing as soon JS is executed. Both `selenium.getEval()` and `(JavaScripDriver) driver.execute()` are throwing exceptions with this error `WebDriverException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed`
Ive tried all combination of browser versions (17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23) &  even tried with v2.34 & v2.35, still no luck. Do you have any suggestions?