# Selenium test wont launch Firefox (java with Netbeans)

Tags: netbeans, selenium

I have Selenium IDE installed on Firefox, I ran a simple test on it and I exported the test cases to Netbeans under Java/JUNIT4/WebDriver. When  I put the code in Netbeans and try to run it, It doesn't launch firefox. I've another simple program that will launch Firefox and go to google and search for cheese but when I try to export a test that I've ran using Selenium IDE, I can't get it to run. I'm not getting any errors and I get "successful build" when I run it, just nothing happens. Here's my code. Thanks

```
> Blockquotepackage firstpackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
//import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class FirstPackage {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
//private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
private boolean acceptNextAlert;
public static void main(String args[]){}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

  driver = new FirefoxDriver();

 driver.get("http://google.com");
 baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/";
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

   System.out.println(driver.getTitle());


}

@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Google");
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfb")).click();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
 driver.quit();
 String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
 if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
```

}

```
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {
  driver.findElement(by);
  return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  return false;
}


}



 private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
 try {
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  if (acceptNextAlert) {
    alert.accept();
  } else {
    alert.dismiss();
  }
  return alert.getText();
 } finally {
   acceptNextAlert = true;
 }

}

}


    // TODO code application logic h

 > Blockquote
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Which versions of Selenium libraries and Firefox browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is likely due to incompatible versions of *Firefox* and *Selenium Firefox WebDriver*.

My guess is that your program that works (the one that goes to Google and searches for cheese) has a different version of Selenium in its path than the one that NetBeans ends up using for your imported tests from the IDE.

For more information on how to deal with the version compatibility issue, see **[my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520739/selenium-firefox-webdriver/18640846#18640846)**.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code on my machine and it worked as expected. Make sure you're using correct jar files and are correctly mapped in your project.